# MySQL - Increase Value by Percentage According to Average

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named instructor.

```
UPDATE instructor
SET salary=salary*1.05
where salary<(select avg(salary) from instructor)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

could be you can't update table based  on a subselect for avoid this you should create dinmically a temp table based on subselect a refer to this

```
UPDATE instructor
SET salary=salary*1.05
where salary< ( 
      select t.my_avg 
      from (
          select avg(salary) my_avg from instructor
      ) t
)
```

Comment: I think this is the solution but there is a little error, you need a t alias after from(...) t

Answer (score 2):

You cannot update a table and use it as a subselect within the same query. Doing so doesn't even make sense.

To accomplish your goal, you'll need to run two different queries. The first will be your subselect. The second query then updates the the table using the first query's result as a parameter.

Query 1:

```
select avg(salary) from instructor
```

Query 2:

```
UPDATE instructor
SET salary=salary*1.05
where salary < @avg_salary
```

Comment: This isn’t an answer

Comment: @Strawberry: It is an answer though. It contains information as to why the query doesn't work and lists how to solve the problem.

Comment: My problem is solved. Thanks. But its also show the avg_salary value. Is there any option to stop showing this?